# How to pass value of GridView from one page to another in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can i pass value of a Grid View from one page to another? This is my code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
        //  //  e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "<a href=" + "javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com')" + " >" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "</a>";
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "<a id=\"linkres\"  CssClass=\"dgrid\" runat =\"server\"  href= \"javascript:window.open('Preview.aspx'),_self\" >" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "</a>";
        }

    }
```

I need to pass the value of the selected item on GridView and then retrieve to another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you need to access some piece of data on multiple pages, you have the following options:

1. Store it in a session variable.
2. Pass it in the querystring of the URL.
3. Store it in a database / pull it on the other page.
4. Store it in a cookie.

For what you're doing, I'd usually go with the first.

```
Session["GridViewValue"] = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
```

And on the other page

```
string something = Session["GridViewValue"].ToString();
```

Comment: If he is using the value in a link he should really think about passing this value in the querystring

Comment: I'm with Gabriel, storing what should actually be "page" state in "session" state is a recipe for problems.

Comment: +1 for listing out the options.  You could also add storing it in a form variable and posting it to the other page.